# How can all the subcomponents present in a form of tab bar be created on loading the application?

Tags: apache-flex

I have a tab bar in which each form (of tab items) has several components. I need to access certain components in certain forms (tab items) which have not been clicked even once. If I try to do so, it returns null values for the components present on the form which has not been clicked once. I have tried using Creation policy set to all, but that is not solving the purpose. I guess setting creation policy to all creates only the forms on application load but not the subcomponents of forms. 
Any pointers in this direction will be really helpfull.

Thanks
Sandy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using ViewStack, set creationPolicy="all" on it - it will create all tabs. Access them after "initialize" event.

Comment: @alxx: ya, I am using viewstack and have the set creation policy to all. But i am not clear about what you mean by accessing them after initialize event? Do I need to set the initialization also programatically. Because in current scenario if i try to access the components of a form which is not clicked, it turns out to be null.

Comment: After main application fires initialize event, its children are created and accessible. It happen automatically, you just need to know life cycle of flex application (well explained here - http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/flex-snippet-tutorial-application-creation-life-cycle-events )

Comment: Yes as alxx says you need to get a better understanding of the life cycle and when the events are fired that let you know everything has been created (generally speaking creationComplete is a major one). Basically you must be trying to access the object before it's been created, setting creation policy to all means even the parts of the tabnav/viewstack that aren't visible will have their containers and children created, this doesn't mean they're immediately accessible when the application loads it still has to create them, when it gets done it'll dispatch a creationComplete event.

Comment: @alxx , @shaunhusain : So do the initialization of each tab in tabbar takes automatically on click only or we can initialize them programatically? Is it feasible to acess the elemnets/components in tab of a tabbar which has not been clicked even once, in any other tab of the same tabbar?

Comment: @sandy: By default, ViewStack uses lazy initialization to save memory, you can change this with creationPolicy="all". Have you tried this?

Comment: @alxx: ya i have tried it as said in initial post only..but dat is not solving the purpose:(:(

Comment: Well, then show relevant parts of your code, I'll try to help.

Comment: @alxx: suggestion in the above answer given by you is working fine...i had done some stupid mistake due to which it didnt seemed to be working for me..anwz thanks:)